# Automatically call superclass method after inherited subclass method

Tags: java, inheritance, aspectj

I have a class `A` where I want `foo` to be called immediately after `blah` is called, including calls to `blah` from subclasses. So below, `B().blah()` will also call `A.foo`. I think this type of thing is possible in Python using decorators, but don't know how to achieve the same effect in Java.

```
class A {
  @protected
  void blah() {
    // pass
  }

  void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo called");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  void blah() {
    System.out.println("blah called");
  }
}
```

In python, something like this works although it still needs the `blah` decorator to be added in the subclass:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def foo(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        retval = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print("foo called")
        return retval
    return wrapper

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    @foo
    def blah(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    @foo
    def blah(self):
        print("blah called")

B().blah()
# prints:
#   blah called
#   foo called
```

Comment: Why does your example show B().foo() calling blah(), when your question asks for B().blah() to call foo()?

Comment: See [Template Method Design Pattern in Java](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/template-method-design-pattern-in-java).

Comment: @tgdavies my bad, updated the names in the python examples to be consistent with the java one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tagged your question with *aspectj*, I am presenting a simple AspectJ solution.

```java
public class A {
  protected void blah() {
    System.out.println("A.blah");
  }

  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("A.foo");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A().blah();
    System.out.println("---");
    new B().blah();
    System.out.println("---");
    new C().blah();
  }
}
```

```java
class B extends A {
  @Override
  protected void blah() {
    System.out.println("B.blah");
  }
}
```

```java
class C extends B {
  @Override
  protected void blah() {
    super.blah();
    System.out.println("C.blah");
  }
}
```

```java
public aspect FooCaller {
  after(A a) : execution(void A.blah()) && target(a) {
    a.foo();
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
A.blah
A.foo
---
B.blah
A.foo
---
B.blah
A.foo
C.blah
A.foo
```

Please note how `A.foo` is called twice when calling `C.blah` because of the `super.blah()` call. If this is not what you want, you need to refine the aspect.

If you want to avoid caling `A.foo` in case of `blah` throwing an exception, you also have to alter the aspect a bit. Your question is somewhat unspecific in this regard.

If you want to avoid `A.foo` to be overridden by subclasses (and hence called by the aspect), you can make the method `final`.

Besides, if you do not like native AspectJ syntax as much as I do, but prefer the more tedious annotation syntax, the equivalent aspect looks like this:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class FooCaller {
  @After("execution(void A.blah()) && target(a)")
  public void interceptBlah(A a) {
    a.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was indeed hoping for an Aspectj solution. As a follow-up question, how would `interceptBlah` get the results from the `blah` call in the case `blah` was non void? I could create another question if the answer is complicated.

Comment: Normally I would ask you to create a new question, but today is Xmas Eve.  Please consult the AspectJ documentation, specifically [`after() returning()`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-advice.html) or [`@AfterReturning`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html), respectively. See also the [language semantics](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html) section.

Comment: If you want to do anything other than read and maybe log the result, such as modify the return value, modify the intercepted method's input parameters, catch exceptions etc., please take a look at `around()` or `@Around`, respectively. You find information about this advice type under the same links as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `blah()` a final method in your base class, with an `onBlah()` method in your child classes which is implemented instead of overriding `blah`. This enforces the calling of `foo()`.

```
abstract class A {
    public final void blah() {
        onBlah();
        foo();
    }

    public final void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo called");
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses implement this to provide blah behaviour
     */
    protected abstract void onBlah();
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void onBlah() {
        System.out.println("Subclass blah");
    }
}

public class So74882376 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().blah();
    }
}
```

Because `blah()` is final, no subclass can break the relationship between calling `blah` and calling `foo`.

`onBlah()` is protected so that we don't pollute the public interface of `A`.

Designing for inheritance is something which needs careful thought. It is often better to use composition.

An alternative to using inheritance here would be to compose an `A` and a `BlahStrategy` instance:

```
interface BlahStrategy {
    public void onBlah();
}

final class A2 {
    private final BlahStrategy blahStrategy;

    public A2(BlahStrategy blahStrategy) {
        this.blahStrategy = blahStrategy;
    }

    public void blah() {
        blahStrategy.onBlah();
        foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo called");
    }
}

public class So74882376 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().blah();
        new A2(() -> System.out.println("my blah action")).blah();
        new A2(() -> System.out.println("another blah action")).blah();
    }
}
```

Of course you can extend `A2` to encapsulate the `BlahStrategy`:

```
final class B2 extends A2 {
   public B2() { super(() -> System.out.println("Subclass blah")); }
}
```

Comment: In the inheritance example, how do we prevent users from calling `B.onBlah`directly? Even though `onBlah` is declared protected, it's still accessible within the same package right?

Comment: That's right -- you can put B in a package where the users of B are not "supposed" to create classes, but I don't think you can actually prevent them calling it. That's another advantage of the composition solution.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can also use `decorator pattern`

Based on your example, try this:

```
class A {
  void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo called");
  }

  void blah() {
    // Implementation of blah
  }
}

class B extends A {
  @Override
  void blah() {
    super.blah();
    foo();
  }
}
```

Now, when you call `blah` on an instance of `B`, the `foo` method will be called immediately after the original implementation of `blah`.

Comment: I don't want to keep having to remember to call foo() in all subclasses though. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Comment: In your solution, the subclass is explicitly calling `foo()`. I want that part to be handled automatically. Something like this discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in this case, try to move `foo();` to be below `// Implementation of blah` and tell me if it meet your needs

Comment: Not really, because now we have to remember to call super.blah() everywhere instead